# Non-degeneracy of curves/manifolds

Tags: manifolds, partial-derivative, curves

Ok so I'm having some problems with understanding what it means for a manifold or curve to be non-degenerate.

The definition I've been trying to get my head around is:
"Non-degeneracy is a generalization of the idea of non-zero curvature and means that for almost all points on the manifold there exists an $l \in \mathbb{N}$  such that the partial derivatives of an appropriate parametrization up to order $l$ span $\mathbb{R}^{n}$."

Then supposedly
$A=\{ (x,x^2,x^3) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \}$
is non-degenerate,
where as
$B=\{ (x,x,x^3) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \}$
is degenerate.

The only thing that I can make sense of is if you take the first, second and third derivatives of $(x,x^2,x^3)$  you get the points $(1,2x,3x^2),(0,2,6x),(0,0,6)$ which of course span $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ for any value of x, whereas you can not do this for B since the first and second components of the point $(x,x,x^3)$ are linearly dependent!

Any help would be much appreciated!